# Count incoming packets on specific network interface

Tags: python, shell, network-programming, packets

I'd like to count the number of incoming packets on a network interface (e.g eth0) for a specific period of time (till 5 minutes after executing the script), how can I do it via shell or python script? which one is more accurate?

I'm aware of network tools such as iptraf but I want it to be done via an script and preferably print the counted value on screen or into a file.

Comment: I think you can use `/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_packets` . it contains only a number, so you just need to check it twice and subtract

Comment: @Duffydake Given the stated problem, that ought be the answer. The other answers, though valid, are certainly overkill for the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using linux shell, you can use `tcpdump` to get the job done. Most of the commands used in the shell are pre-installed in most linux distributions.

```
#!/bin/sh
# # # Run this as sudo
# # # Pass an argument of your IP address
# # $ Usage: sudo ./<nameOfTheScript> <IPofYourMachine>
# Parameters
captureTime=300


# Capture packets for X Seconds
tcpdump -i eth0 dst host $1 >> /dev/null 2> out &
pid=$!
sleep $captureTime
kill $pid

# Extract relevant data
cat out | tail -2 | head -1 | cut -d " " -f 1

# Cleaning up!
rm out
```

The shell runs `tcpdump` for `300` seconds and terminates it. `tcpdump` outputs the data that your require to `stderr`. That would be the reason to redirect that stream to a file (`2> out`). The last-second command of the shell extracts the data that we want from the full message that's thrown from `tcpdump`. It requires to be run as `sudo`! Also don't forget to modify the listening interface as required.

If it's still not clear about why I've done what I've done, let me know!

Comment: `tcpdump -i eth0` will capture outgoing packets too. You should add `ip dst $Ipaddr` or an equivalent to make sure you've got only incoming packets

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but missed it while writing the script! Anyways the edit should the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works for me like a charm :-)
There's only one thing, for some generated traffics it seems doesn't work properly (e.g 5Gb/s or upper)  I don't get any accurate value, how can I fix it?

Comment: @Sina Sh Use kernel files instead of libpcap based tool, it's faster and more reliable for high speed connection, see my answer.

Comment: So does the script work for incoming and sending packets or only incoming ?

Answer (score 2):

Check out https://github.com/dugsong/pypcap it uses libpcap and it looks like it supports linux/win/mac

```
>>> import pcap
>>> for ts, pkt in pcap.pcap():
...     print ts, `pkt`
```

someone posted a longer example script here:
http://pylibpcap.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 2):

You can use `/sys/class/net/INTERFACE/statistics/rx_packets` if you are using Linux Kernel (I don't know about BSD, ... kernels)

capture.sh interface time_in_seconds

```
#!/bin/sh
pcksFile="/sys/class/net/$1/statistics/rx_packets"
nbPcks=`cat $pcksFile`
sleep $2
echo $(expr `cat $pcksFile` - $nbPcks)
```

Output :

```
$ ./capture.sh eth0 2
7
```

Comment: This gives me "permission denied" error, even though I'm the root on machine, tried "sudo" and got " command not found " for it...
chmod +x is done on the file, result still the same,

Comment: FYI it's Debian 3.16.7

Comment: I tried on a debian 3.15.9 and it works fine even with a "simple" user (root/sudo is not needed): `touch capture.sh` , `nano capture.sh` copy/paste  the script , `chmod +x capture.sh` and then `./capture.sh eth0 10` . My rx_packets file permission is `-r--r--r--`by default